# android soundpool heapsize overflow

Tags: android, overflow, soundpool

I get this error hundreds of times when I run in Debug, it doesn't seem to affect the program, but how do I get rid of it?

I know it can be traced back to the SoundPool based on other posts

09-15 09:03:09.190: ERROR/AudioCache(34): Heap size overflow! req size: 1052672, max size: 1048576

Comment: Then just increase your heap size

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap.html

Comment: On which device do you have that error ? It occured  also on galaxytab10.1

Comment: @Roflcoptr that is a terrible suggestion, and one that is not applicable on Android. Apps don't have the ability to set JVM heap size on Android.

Comment: Do you get this error when you play a sound? Or nevertheless?

Comment: Soundpool isn't designed to hold a large amount of data, just small collection of sound effects. Consider using MediaPlayer as an alternative if needed.

Answer (score 12):

SoundPool is hard code the buffer size as 1M for all loaded file. So you probably will get 'heap size overflow' error when you load too much files into SoundPool. I also have this issue on a game project that will load game sound FX into SoundPool and the solution is as follow:

1. Play long/large background music in MediaPlayer.
2. Play short sound files in multi SoundPool instances to prevent the heap error. The sample code for multi SoundPools:

```
 /**
  * Multi SoundPool to prevent memory error.
  */
public class SoundPools {
```

private static final String TAG = "SoundPools";

  private static final int MAX_STREAMS_PER_POOL = 15;

  private List<SoundPoolContainer> containers;

  public SoundPools() {
    containers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<SoundPoolContainer>());
  }

  public void loadSound(Context context, String id, String file) {
    Log.d(TAG, "SouldPools load sound " + file);
    try {
      for (SoundPoolContainer container : containers) {
        if (container.contains(id)) {
          return;
        }
      }
      for (SoundPoolContainer container : containers) {
        if (!container.isFull()) {
          container.load(context, id, file);
          return;
        }
      }
      SoundPoolContainer container = new SoundPoolContainer();
      containers.add(container);
      container.load(context, id, file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Load sound error", e);
    }
  }

  public void playSound(Context context, String id, String file) {
    Log.d(TAG, "SouldPools play sound " + file);
    try {
      for (SoundPoolContainer container : containers) {
        if (container.contains(id)) {
          container.play(context, id, file);
          return;
        }
      }
      for (SoundPoolContainer container : containers) {
        if (!container.isFull()) {
          container.play(context, id, file);
          return;
        }
      }
      SoundPoolContainer container = new SoundPoolContainer();
      containers.add(container);

      container.play(context, id, file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Play sound error", e);
    }
  }

  public void onPause() {
    for (SoundPoolContainer container : containers) {
      container.onPause();
    }
  }

  public void onResume() {
    for (SoundPoolContainer container : containers) {
      container.onResume();
    }
  }

  private static class SoundPoolContainer {
    SoundPool soundPool;
    Map<String, Integer> soundMap;
    AtomicInteger size;

    public SoundPoolContainer() {
      this.soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS_PER_POOL, android.media.AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
      this.soundMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>(MAX_STREAMS_PER_POOL);
      this.size = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    public void load(Context context, String id, String file) {
      try {
        this.size.incrementAndGet();
        soundMap.put(id, soundPool.load(context.getAssets().openFd(file), 1));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        this.size.decrementAndGet();
        Log.w(TAG, "Load sound error", e);
      }
    }

    public void play(Context context, String id, String file) {
      android.media.AudioManager audioManager = (android.media.AudioManager) context
          .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      final int streamVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(android.media.AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      Integer soundId = soundMap.get(id);
      if (soundId == null) {
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
          @Override
          public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            soundPool.play(sampleId, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
          }
        });
        try {
          this.size.incrementAndGet();
          soundPool.load(context.getAssets().openFd(file), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          this.size.decrementAndGet();
          Log.w(TAG, "Load/Play sound error", e);
        }
      } else {
        try {
          soundPool.play(soundId, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.w(TAG, "Play sound error", e);
        }
      }
    }

    public boolean contains(String id) {
      return soundMap.containsKey(id);
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
      return this.size.get() >= MAX_STREAMS_PER_POOL;
    }

    public void onPause() {
      try {
        soundPool.autoPause();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Pause SoundPool error", e);
      }
    }

    public void onResume() {
      try {
        soundPool.autoResume();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Resume SoundPool error", e);
      }
    }
  }

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your media resource is too big for playing with soundpool. Soundpool only plays short sound effects. On the Soundpool API there is no specification about the maximum of a resource for playing with soundpool, but if You use it, play just short sound effects like, for example, a short explosion in a shooter game.
If this is Your problem, You should use MediaPlayer for playing your sounds.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for this error to be about heap size, because there aren't any device with such a small heap 1052672 ~ 1Mb., but about `SoundPool` buffer size. 
`SoundPool` has hardcoded limit of 1Mb of raw `PCM_16` data in memory. This limit applies for every sound you are loading into memory, and not for sounds in sum per one `SoundPool`. So the most voted answer about `SoundPools` is very wrong!

Let me introduce `SoundPoolCompat` which uses `AudioTrack` under the hood and have custom `bufferSize`. All data within specified buffer will be loaded into memory and played with small latency like `SoundPool` does. All data that exceed that `bufferSize` will be loaded on demand (which adds latency, similar to `MediaPlayer`). Api is very similart to `SoundPool`, also it is added a feature to load sounds from Uri (for example gdrive). And there is `playOnce` method, all resources will be unloaded after file is played.

```
implementation 'com.olekdia:sound-pool:3.0.2'
```

https://gitlab.com/olekdia/common/libraries/sound-pool