# Android SoundPool: Does Heap Size Overflow Matter?

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I'm developing an app in Android and I employ the SoundPool API. I have a large amount of ogg files (over 70) that I have loaded into a single SoundPool instance.

I constantly see a message about the heap size overflow in my logs at runtime.

```
02-16 12:50:27.289: ERROR/AudioCache(23363): Heap size overflow! req size: 1050624, max size: 1048576
```

My question is not how to get rid of this error. I can do so by instantiating multiple SoundPools and dividing my ogg files between them. (As seen here: [android soundpool heapsize overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428448/android-soundpool-heapsize-overflow))

**My question is**; does a heap size overflow matter? Even though my app constantly throws this log message I have not noticed any bugged behavior (all 70+ files seem to play back great with no perceivable latency). What implications does a heap size overflow have for an Android SoundPool?